# how to setup wordpress android project

Tags: android, wordpress

I am a newbie to Android development. I am having trouble building a project.

Revision 836, Oct 8 2012
Eclipse classic : Version: 4.2.0 Build id: I20120608-1400

Android SDK: 4.1.2 API 16

After I imported the Wordpress Android project. I got lots of errors.

see here: [errors screenshot](http://blackgun.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/eclipse-error.gif)

I set:

> default.properties

```
target=android-16
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion=”8”
android:targetSdkVersion=”16” />
```

It doesn’t work.

The error is caused by override, so I guess it didn’t find the right lib and class.

How do I setup the project?

Comment: Have you checked to see what version your Java compiler is set to? I have heard of this issue being present on many imported projects that were compiling with 1.5 and not 1.6, if it is 1.5 then change to 1.6, it should rebuild the project. Let me know if that works. (`Project>Properties>Java Compiler`)

Comment: But, there are 102 warning items. Such as: the constructor BitmapDrawable(Bitmap) is deprecated (ImageHelper.java, SimpleWebImageCache.java,...).  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.Fill_PARENT is deprecated (Preferences.java,...)

Comment: Deprecation is something you should address but warnings will not stop your application from running. My suggestion is to find time to go through each deprecated method and do some research as to why it is deprecated and what is the best coarse of action.

Comment: For example, the [Documentation for BitmapDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable()) suggests "Use `BitmapDrawable(Resources)` to ensure that the drawable has correctly set its target density."

Comment: Sure, it is compiled and work well on my Nexus S. Thanks.

Comment: I found lots of method is deprecated, maybe hundreds of them. Does it mean android lib is unstable and often changed? If that was true, it is terrible for developing android app.

Comment: Deprecation more or less means that it is an older way of doing things, in other words processes were changed or deemed unnecessary (in some cases). It really only effects future versions of Android, meaning they no longer are supported methods/declarations. The ones you mentioned are Android specific, not Wordpress. I think of Deprecation as moving forward and getting better, otherwise developing in any environment would be depressing, deprecation is everywhere in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Java Compiler Compliance level, Eclipse defaults this to 1.5, which can only Override superclass methods (which is what your error log shows is the problem). If your project Overrides interface methods then you will need to change this to 1.6.

You can change this by:

```
Project>Properties>Java Compiler
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide us with the error output. check if the "Android SDK" installation path is correctly configured in eclipse, you can check this going to "Window" > "Preferences" > "Android"

Comment: C:\Development\Android SDK, it is installed correctly. I can build my project from scratch.